# comparing form input to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html

## file.html

```
<div id="id00" class="login">
    <form class="modal-content animate" action="chat1.php" method="POST">
        <div class="cross">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
            <label><b>Password</b></label>     
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

## chat1.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $dbname = "login";
    $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("unable to connect to MySQL");
    if(isset($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]))
    {
        $user = $_POST["username"];
        $pass = $_POST["password"];
        $result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username = '".$user."'");
        $result2 = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE password = '".$pass."'");
        if($user == $result2 && $pass == $result1)
        {
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $name;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "incorrect username/password";
        }
    }
?>
```

---

I need to check the username and password with the datatbase and allow login.In my code its always giving me incorrect. can anyone help me out?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: i dont understand, why you are doing two querys to mysql, and not one with user and password, and get one row from it

Comment: In addition to @ÁlvaroTouzón, one more thing, you missed mysqli_query(`$dbhandle`, "SELECT... here

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i tried that too.. but its still giving me incorrect.. do you want me to share that code too>

Comment: @ABCatella where should i place that?

Comment: `mysqli_query($dbhandle, "SELECT your query`

Comment: do you do @ABCatella saids?

Comment: @ABCatella it still gives me incorrect username/password

Comment: yeah i did that @ÁlvaroTouzón.. before i was getting some errors.. but now there are no errors but it gives incorrect

Comment: Do you have a table `login` in the database `login` ?

Comment: yes @ABCatella.. i got the problem resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $dbname = "login";
        $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("unable to connect to MySQL");
        if(isset($_POST["username"],$_POST["password"]))
        {
            $user = $_POST["username"];
            $pass = $_POST["password"];
            $result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username = '".$user."' and password = '".$pass."'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result1))
            { 
                $result = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
                $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
                $_SESSION["naam"] = $result['username'];
$redirect="yoursuccessurl.php";
            }
            else
            {
                $redirect="yourfailureurl.php";
            }
        }

header("location: ".$redirect);
    ?>
```

Note all these codes are open to sql injection

Comment: if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)).. what are comparing it with?
should it be like-  if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0)  ?

Comment: If rows > 0, it returns true else returns false

Comment: soo should i use it like-  if(mysqli_num_rows($result1))?

Comment: here it redirects me to a black page after the login.. what should i do if i want to stay on the same page @ABCatella ?

Comment: can i just have an echo at the else part instead of $redirect?

Answer (score 0):

**You never select username from password**
reason being: many users can have have same password and for security reasons passwords should be hashed and stored.

This line is a bad query.

```
  $result2 = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE password = '".$pass."'");
```

What you should do is

```
 $result1 = mysqli_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username = '".$user."'");
if($pass == $result1)
        {
            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
            $_SESSION["naam"] = $name;
        }
```